# $L^2$ bound and interpolation of Hölder norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the function

$$F(x):=\int_{\mathbb R} f(t+x)f(t-x) \ dt .$$

Clearly, we have by Cauchy-Schwarz

$$\vert F(x) \vert\le \Vert f \Vert^2_{L^2} $$
$$\vert F'(x)\vert\le 2\Vert f' \Vert_{L^2} \Vert f \Vert_{L^2} \le 2\Vert f \Vert_{H^1}^2$$

where $H^1$ is the $L^2$-Sobolev space of order 1.

This shows that to bound the sup norm of $F$ we require $f \in L^2$ and to bound the $C^1$ norm of $F$ it suffices to have $f \in H^1.$

I wonder now if it is true that the Hölder norm $C^{\gamma}$ with $\gamma \in (0,1)$ can be bounded by the $H^{\gamma}$ norm of $f$ and if that is not the case, I would be curious to learn what the correct interpolation space for $f$ is to bound the Hölder norm of $F$.

Comment: Nitpick: the estimates you describe don't show that you *require* $f\in L^2$ or $f\in H^1$, they merely show that such conditions are **sufficient**.

Comment: Also, in your first integral, surely you mean $dt$ not $dx$

Comment: Finally: if you just want sufficient conditions on $f$ to ensure $F$ is in a certain H\"older class, then a natural idea would be to look at conditions on the decay rate of the Fourier transform of $F$ which ensure $F$ itself has the right H\"older continuity, then use the fact that $F(x) = (f*g)(2x)$ where $g(t)=f(-t)$

Comment: @YemonChoi thank you for the first two corrections. Regarding your third comment, I am not quite sure I understand how to apply it. So roughly the Fourier transform of $F$ is the product of $\widehat{f}$ with itself up to some factors. What is then the condition for the Hölder space?

Comment: I don't have the relevant texts in front of me, but there are some fairly classical theorems relating the Hoelder continuity of a function with the decay rate of its Fourier transform. Katznelson's book on harmonic analysis has this, IIRC, but such results should be in other texts as well

Comment: @YemonChoi already sobolev embeddings relate the hölder norm to the decay of a fourier transform. However, the question on the other hand is whether this can be done in a sharp way.

Comment: @Tokoyo Firstly, the OP was asking about conditions on F in terms of f; I am pointing out that the question simplifies to the kinds of results you describe. Also, as I attempted to point out to the OP, I don't see what is sharp about the original sufficient conditions that he or she lists, and if that is his or her question, then that is what he or she should have asked

Comment: @YemonChoi Sorry, the point I tried to make was that the OP asks specifically whether it is possible to bound the Hölder norm in terms of the fractional Sobolev norm. Although you are correct that you can get a bound using the methods you describe, I am not sure it is that one.

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is correct. Define the bilinear operator $T$ by
$$
T(f,g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t+x)g(t-x)\,dt.
$$
As you have shown, this operator is bounded from $L^2\times L^2\to C^0$ and from $H^1\times H^1\to C^1$. It follows from bilinear real interpolation theory (see e.g. Zafran, [A multilinear interpolation theorem](https://eudml.org/doc/218179)) that $T$ is also bounded from $(L^2,H^1)_{\theta,p}\times (L^2,H^1)_{\theta,q}\to (C^0,C^1)_{\theta,r}$ whenever $\theta\in (0,1)$ and $p,q,r\in [1,\infty]$ satisfiy $1/r+1=1/p+1/q$.

If we take $r=\infty$ and $p=q=2$ and use $(L^2,H^1)_{\gamma,2}=H^\gamma$, $(C^0,C^1)_{\gamma,\infty}=C^\gamma$, we obtain the desired boundedness from $H^\gamma\times H^\gamma\to C^\gamma$.